# VBA Autofill series starting at last cell with value and continuing to last row of adjacent columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have seen similar questions on this subject, however no answers that are working for me. I'm trying to automate the autofill to continue a series (HT-1, HT-2, HT-3...etc.) down to the last row of spreadsheet. Basically I import new rows that won't have values in the B column. After importing more new rows I need to continue the series in B to the end of the new rows. I'm getting an error with the AutoFill method. Any suggestions?

[image: pic of sheet]

[image: debug]

```
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim main As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim typeLastrow As Long

Set main = wb.Sheets("hangers")

lastRow = main.Cells(main.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
typeLastrow = main.Range("B" & main.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B" & typeLastrow).AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & typeLastrow & ":B" & lastRow)
End Sub
```

Comment: Put `main.` in front of both instances of `Range` in that line.

Comment: I just tried. Same error.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print Range("B" & typeLastrow).Value, typeLastrow, lastRow` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: This what I get -           13             13

Comment: Those results suggest that `B5:B13` are not actually empty, and contain a `-`.

Comment: it was just the 13 13, no dash

Comment: Either way, if you're getting `13 13`, then either `B13` is not empty (blank string perhaps?). Or maybe you're working with a table (`ListObject`), in which case there's a different approach to find the last row. Though it doesn't appear that you're working with a table from your screenshot.

Comment: Do `B5:B13` contain formula or a space?  Try this: `Debug.Print "'" & Range("B" & typeLastrow).Formula & "'", typeLastrow, lastRow`  Or you can highlight the "empty" cells and hit delete and see if the code works after that.

Comment: No success. The cells are blank and it's not a table.

Comment: Now it seems to be working. I'll edit the code to show what it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim main As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim typeLastrow As Long

Set main = wb.Sheets("hangers")

lastRow = main.Cells(main.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
typeLastrow = main.Cells(main.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
main.Range("B" & typeLastrow).AutoFill Destination:=main.Range("B" & typeLastrow & ":B" & lastRow)

End Sub
```